# Can't install any theme Prestashop

Tags: installation, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have install fresh versions of Prestashop 1.7.5.2 and 1.7.6.1 on my Linux computer and I can't install themes on any them. I have tried with these free themes [Apparel](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/958333-free-theme-apparel-%E2%80%93-multipurpose-responsive-free-prestashop-theme/) and [ST002](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/987062-free-themes-fashion-prestashop-free-themes/) and I always get some error with a module of the type:

"Cannot install module XXXX. The module is invalid and cannot be loaded."

I think it has to do with something in my Prestashop installation, not with the themes themselves. But I don't have any idea where to start looking, could you please help me? This is getting me mad.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check for permissions? `chmod 644` on `/modules` and  `/themes`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with 775 for directories and 664 for files on the prestashop directory and the error is still there.

Comment: Try removing module _XXXX_, from the theme's installation zip. Zip it again and install it.

Comment: Removing the modules with error from the /dependencies folder didn't work. I have to remove them from the config/theme.yml file, but then the shop wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to install the theme by putting the theme's directory into the "themes" directory of my prestashop.

But the proper way to install a theme is by providing a zip file to the administration interface.

If you put the directory manually in "theme" you will also have to manually copy the modules inside the dependency directory of your theme to the "modules" directory of your prestashop.

Manually copying modules might not be enough since it won't call the "install" method on the modules.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the specs/requirements of the theme? Maybe the theme you want to install is not compatible with the current Prestashop version you using. Especially the version 1.7.6, there's alot of changes/update made.

Answer (score 1):

After much try and error I have found a solution. I have taken each module folder under the dependencies directory of the theme and make a zip file with it. Then I have installed each module with the zip from the administration module dashboard. After installing all the modules, I'm able to install the theme without errors and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if those modules(which give errors) exist in a theme dependencies directory and remove them one by one from the directory and all dependencies from theme.yml file in a config directory. It just may be that themes are outdated and contain outdated modules

Comment: I have removed all the references to the modules that give error in the config/theme.yml and finally I'm able to install the themes. The problem is that most of the shop doesn't work as it needs these modules.

Is there any other option to make the shop work properly with full theme functionallity?

Thank for your help!

Comment: You need to update each module in accordance with new Prestashop requirements. Also, you can ask the themes developer, maybe they have updatet versions